# Interpreting intercept with centered predictors in logistic mixed model

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, intercept, centering

I am running a logistic mixed model in lme4. The model is as follows

```r
logme <- glmer(Correct ~ PE_Condition.ct*sumspq + (1|Pt_ID), 
    family = binomial, data = test_CorrectPred.ct, 
    control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

I have one continuous predictor which is a questionnaire score (sumspq). I also have a categorical predictor (PE_Condition) with two levels: 0= 'low' and 1= 'high'.

My dependent variable is correct/incorrect responses.

In accordance with Jaeger (2008), I have centered both predictors to reduce multicollinearity (as there is an interaction).

1. I want to check my understanding of the intercept.

I believe the intercept assesses whether the log-likelihood of producing a correct response is significantly greater than 50% when a participant has a mean spq score?

2. This is a 3AFC task, meaning participants have 3 response options and only 1 is correct. Chance level is therefore 1/3 rather than 50%. Out of interest, is there any way to reflect this in the intercept (to assess chance performance as 33% rather than 50%)? I'm not quite understanding why centering makes the intercept as 50%.

[image: These are the results from running this model]

Reference: Jaeger TF. Categorical Data Analysis: Away from ANOVAs (transformation or not) and towards Logit Mixed Models. J Mem Lang. 2008 Nov;59(4):434-446. doi: 10.1016/j.jml.2007.11.007. PMID: 19884961; PMCID: PMC2613284.

Comment: What are you trying to learn from your model exactly? The focus is usually on quantifying the effect of changes in the predictor(s), the intercept is there to model the response for all other predictor values being 0. It doesn't have much to do with response over or under 50% rather than that being the back-transformation for log-odds of *all* parameters (including intercept) being 0, and that also being the default hypothesis test.

Comment: Please add the full reference for Jaeger 2008. The intercept is the predicted log-odds of being correct if both predictors are at their means. The corresponding hypothesis test tests the null that the intercept is 0, i.e. that the probability is 50%. To change this to a null of 1/3, calculate the test statistic as $(\hat{\beta}-(-\log(2))/\mathrm{SE}$, where $\mathrm{SE}$ is the standard error. Then use `pnorm` to calculate the p-value. The $-\log(2)$ is the log-odds for a probability of 1/3, if you're wondering.

Comment: @COOLSerdash thank you. I presume the beta hat here would be the intercept estimate? For my first question, do you know if the interpretation of the intercept is correct in this case?

Comment: Yes, $\hat{\beta}$ is just the estimated intercept. Your interpretation is almost correct but a bit imprecise. The intercept is the predicted log-odds (not log-likelihood) for being correct if all predictors are 0 (which means at their means if you centered them).

Comment: Great, thanks so much. For the intercept interpretation, I understand that the continuous predictor sumspq will have its mean at the intercept. However, the categorical variable is also centered. I'm therefore uncertain how this can be interpreted.

Comment: Yeah, centering the binary predictor in this case is very questionable, in my opinion. If you left is as it was, the intercept would be the log-odds of being correct if sumspq is average and PE_Condition was "low".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested in future, I attempt to answer Q1 to the best of my ability. In this explanation, 'centering' refers to grand-mean centering. The binary predictor is dummy coded.

I would recommend two papers that provide insight into centering categorical predictors in mixed models:

Enders, Craig K, and Davood Tofighi. "Centering Predictor Variables in Cross-Sectional Multilevel Models." Psychological Methods 12.2 (2007): 121-38. Web.

Yaremych, Haley E, Kristopher J Preacher, and Donald Hedeker. "Centering Categorical Predictors in Multilevel Models: Best Practices and Interpretation." Psychological Methods 28.3 (2023): 613-30. Web.

Of particular relevance is Enders & Tofighi's (2007) detailed explanation of interpreting the intercept with a level 1 binary predictor (equivalent to my high vs low PE_Condition variable) on pg 134.

In my example, the intercept for a model with only 'PE_Condition' (high vs low) included as a fixed effect would be the adjusted mean log-odds of producing a correct response. The mean is 'adjusted' as it is conditional on an equal proportion of 'high' and 'low' responses for each participant. Given the inclusion of a random participant intercept, this intercept will vary between participants.

Adding the (centered) continuous predictor 'sumspq' to the model will change the intercept to be the adjusted mean log-odds of producing a correct response, holding sumspq constant at the grand mean.

For my study, this intercept is not particularly useful, and I am focusing instead on the main effects and interaction. However, it is recommended to center both continuous and categorical predictors to reduce collinearity in models with interactions (refer to the above papers as well as Jaeger (2008) in my original question for further details).